# Rewrite URL for subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem. I have site *site.com* with directory *store* on the hosting. When I type *site.com* I want to open *site.com/store* but I want to show URL *site.com*.

I tried to make .htaccess file but no result.

Comment: PYovchevski, I edited you question to make it clearer. Please check if it's still OK and edit it to show the .htaccess file contents that you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^((?!store/).*) /store/$1 [L,NC]
```